# Add existing OS's to bootberry(or alternatives)

Tags: noobs, berryboot

So I have 3 use drives:
128gb w/retropie 
32gb w/raspbian
8gb w/libreelec

Is there a way to have all 3 connected at once and have an sd card with something like berryboot/pinn/noobs where I can select which one I want to boot from? As of currently I have been switching out as needed but I bought a nespi case and want to have them all internal.

Comment: Yes.  You've answered your own question.  I've used Berryboot to do exactly that but have you tried it?  So you've read about it - does it do what you want?  What's your question?

Comment: Yes I have tried berryboot but couldn't get it to detect the os's that were already there. It would only allow me to install new ones. So is there a way for it to detect each os instead of having to reinstall and set them up again?

Comment: Yes berryboot has a button for adding a new OS.

Comment: Ok so I tried berryboot again to check and all it tells me is to format a drive so inserted a blank usb formatted and reboot. Now I'm in the menu editor with my existing retropie os plugged in but see no option to boot from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you want is just a basic install of BerryBoot. One of its many features is the ability to plugin a external USB and use that to boot all the other images. BerryBoot can auto install RetroPi if it detects you have a powerful enough system. (Pi2/3 are good, Pi0 tested and failed)

https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot

Steps to get RetroPi working on an external USB:

1. Follow the steps in the URL above to install basic BerryBoot. Format SD in FAT and copy files to the drive. Then boot the OS and follow the steps.
2. BerryBoot will ask where you want to store your OS images. This stage is confusing, but its asking where you want the DATA to be stored; you will always need the SD card. **This is where you choose external USB.**
3. BerryBoot will ask you what images (OSes) you want to download and install. At this step you would choose RetroPi (make sure your controllers are plugged in)
4. BerryBoot will download the image and install all the needed drivers (this is why you need the controllers plugged in)

After everything is done, it will go back to the BerryBoot OS and you can select others or boot to RetroPi. It is also possible to set one of the images as default to auto load after a few seconds. (default behavior with just one)